# Using Google Forms inside Android Application

Tags: android, google-forms, google-api-java-client, google-forms-api

I am a bit confused as of how to access Google Forms Api inside Android App.
I would like to access users Google Forms, create Google Form, send answers to Google Form, from inside my Android Application.

I can find it on API list https://developers.google.com/gsuite/products. But it doesn't have any external api for Android.

If I look at special list for client libraries, there is no Google Forms API, but there is API for slides, sheets, and all other google docs products. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/

Comment: there is unfortunately no Google Forms (or Google Docs) API at this point. Let's hope 2019 changes that.

Comment: What do you mean by "API for Android"? We can use the REST API on pretty much any platform. And [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) might suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Besides using a browser automation tool, there two ways to programmatically create and modify Google Forms, using Google Apps Script and Google Forms API launched relatively recently.

The details are in the https://developers.google.com/forms